# Moodle $DB function

Tags: php, database, moodle

i have been researching moodle right now and cant seem to find the rightanswers...

```
public static function exists($user, $course){
    return self::$DB->record_exists('completion_ext', array(
        'user_id'=>$user,
        'course'=>$course

    ));
}
```

i created this code and tried to echoed it... the class of the function is named `completion_ext`, so when I go

```
echo completion_ext::exists(1, 3);
```

it should echo `true` or `false` right? need help please

when i do the code said above, it is blank... its not true, nor false, just blank

Comment: It depends on what `record_exists()` returns. Also it's not really clear what the problem is - what *is* it returning that is making you ask?

Answer (score 0):

> it should echo `true` or `false` right?

No. It does echo *nothing* (`false`) or `1` (`true`). See [boolean to string conversion in the manual](http://php.net/manual/language.types.type-juggling.php). Using `echo` will make PHP to convert everything to string.

Answer (score 0):

This will return boolean value true or false but when you echo the boolean result it is cast into a string which converts the boolean value to a 1 for true or nothing for false.

If you are not getting 1 when you believe you should be, make sure there are no database query problems by doing this.

```
public static function exists($user, $course){
    try {
        return self::$DB->record_exists('completion_ext', array(
            'user_id'=>$user,
            'course'=>$course

        ));
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        if (!empty($ex->error)) {
            echo $ex->error;  // since dml_exception stores it here
        }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't help, make sure that you have debugging turned on and all the way up from the administration settings (just do a search for debug) and make sure you print the header before you call into your function. I assume your class sets the local $DB param to the system global $DB param?

Answer (score 0):

Declare $DB variable before using it.